# inlinelisting adds a space after keywords

Tags: listings, inline

I am having problem with `lstinline` macro. It keeps adding a space after the keyword "Module" - see MWE. How could I convince Latex not to do so?

I already tried with including the "." inside the `\koda` argument, but then I get 2 spaces onward.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{listings} 

\newcommand{\koda}[1]{%
\lstinline[language=[Visual]Basic,keywordstyle=\ttfamily\color{blue}, %
basicstyle=\rmfamily\normalsize, prebreak=, %
morekeywords={Or, Loop, Until, To, As, Single, Module, Double, ByVal}]
{#1}} %

\begin{document}
An example with \koda{Console, Sub et Module}. Continued text ...
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your MWE is too minimal this time. You need to add `\usepackage{xcolor}`. Also, you should put curly braces around the language selection, as in `\lstinline[language={[Visual]Basic},...]`, because otherwise there are issues with the parsing of the square brackets. With these fixes, I do not see the space between 'Module' and the '.' that you are talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you fix your example by adding curly braces around the language and loading `xcolor`, there aren't any issues with the spacing *after* the code.  But there is still an issue with spacing  *before*: there's an extra space.  I've tried taking out spaces and putting in `%`'s, and nothing seems to fix it.  Also, it seems to be specific to `[Visual]Basic`; if you try `[Visual]C++`, the extra space goes away.  If you delete the language setting within the `\lstinline`, and use a `\lstset{language=[Visual]Basic}` outside the `\koda` definition, the space also goes away.  Maybe a bug somewhere in the Visual Basic definition?

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings} 

\newcommand{\koda}{%
  \lstinline[language={[Visual]Basic},
    keywordstyle=\ttfamily\color{blue},
    basicstyle=\rmfamily\normalsize,
    prebreak=,
    morekeywords={Or, Loop, Until, To, As, Single, Module, Double, ByVal}]}

\begin{document}

An example with LEFT\koda{Console, Sub et Module}RIGHT. Continued text ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: In this case I would consider to define `\koda` *with no argument*, leaving off `{#1}`, so that one could use all the features of `\lstinline` such as \koda!text!, avoiding premature tokenization.

Comment: @egreg I agree, that's a better approach.  I've edited the answer.  Unfortunately, the extra space is still present, and still goes away for `language={[Visual]C++}`.

Comment: Thank you both for your ideas. I used the curly braces around the language definition and left out the argument to `\koda`.

Answer (score 4):

The space before is a bug in `lstmisc.sty` (2007/02/22 v1.4) in the following "aspect",
line 849:

```
\lst@BeginAspect[keywords,comments]{keywordcomments}
...
\lst@ProvideFamily@@
    \lst@KCAkeywordsB@list\lst@KCAkeywordsB \lst@KC@also
    \lst@gKCAkeywordsB@list\lst@gKCAkeywordsB \lst@KCAWorkB
    {kcb}owo % prefix, other key, working procedure, Output hook
...
\lst@EndAspect
```

Line 849 should remove the space before the comment:

```
    {kcb}owo% prefix, other key, working procedure, Output hook
```

(The next lines without the comment work, because the end of line character 13 (`^^M`) has catcode 9 for ignore.)

### Workaround

If the language is loaded in the preamble, the white space is executed in vertical mode causing no harm:

```
\lstloadlanguages{[Visual]Basic}
```

Comment: PLEASE IGNORE THE ABOVE COMMENT. Could not delete it :(

I tried fixing the bug and removing the space in `lstmisc.sty` and it did not help. However, using `lstset{...}` not straight before `lstinline` solved the extra space problem.